# Browser specfic stylesheet for mozilla & chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mozilla

How can i declare different CSS style sheet for different browser (mainly MozillaFF & chrome)? I have seen many answers on stack overflow by javascript. Is there any other way to do?

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't need to. Firefox and Chrome are both very standards compliant these days, there shouldn't be many differences between how they render the page. (Unless you really did mean the Mozilla Browser which Mozilla stopped making many, many years ago after they started producing Firefox instead … but that's unusable on the WWW)

Comment: Firefox it is. I have already tried to reset the css element, but one of my form has different sizes when opened in this 2 browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can target specific browsers in your `css` file

```
-moz-height: 20px; //firefox specific css
-webkit-height: 20px; // chrome specific css
```

Comment: Tried the following but not working 
#filter-details form {
 -moz-line-height: 1.8px;
 -webkit-line-height: 1.5px;
}

Answer (score 0):

you can use -webkit- prefix with css properties for chrome
and can use -moz- prefix with css properties for Mozilla Firefox.